# How to add a some class when screen size is smaller than xxx px?

Tags: jquery

I m trying to create a mobile menu for my new project width slidetoogle function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.allCategories').click(function(event) {
        $('.categoryContainner').slideToggle('300');
    });


    var mobileMenu = $(window).width();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      mobileMenu = $(window).width();
      if (mobileMenu < 440) {

          $('#allCategroyList').addClass('class_name')();
      }
    });

});
```

html :

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="content">
        <span class="info">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Hello we have <strong>2711</strong> HD quality documantary videos in <strong>51</strong> categories.
        </span>
        <span class="allCategories">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i> All Categories
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="categoryContainner">
        <div class="content">
            <nav id="allCategroyList">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 8</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Category Link 10</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It did not worked for me ? Can anyone help me please. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The solution is,

```
var mobileMenu = $(window).width();

        $(window).resize(function() {
          mobileMenu = $(window).width();
          if (mobileMenu < 440) {

              $('#allCategroyList').addClass('class_name');
          }
        });
```

Thanks for fast replay.

Comment: what is the reason for adding that extra `();` out there..? `.addClass('class_name')();`

Comment: use @media-query http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: oh my.. thats a point. it all about my sublime emmet pluging auto complate tags :D thanks for fast replay. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove that extra set of parenthesis after the `addClass()` statement, because it will cause the following error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

```
  $('#allCategroyList').addClass('class_name')();
                                  ------------^
```

Comment: Thank you, @Rajaprabhu Aravindasam ;)